# How to access command line parameters in build definition?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to be able to modify some build tasks in response to command line parameters. How do I (can I?) access command line parameters from the Build.scala file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible and you should rather resort to using [input tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html) or environment properties with `-D`.